# How does closure affect a for loop?

Tags: javascript

I have been trying to understand why the following code snippet behaves as it does:

```
    for (var i=1; i<=5; i++) {
        setTimeout( function timer(){
            console.log( i );
        }, i*1000 );
    }  //prints 6 five times with a gap of one second in between each
```

Why the 6? I have seen some explanations but I still couldn't understand. Also why does the code below work?

```
    for (var i=1; i<=5; i++) {
        (function(){
            var j = i;
            setTimeout( function timer(){
                console.log( j );
            }, j*1000 );
        })();
    }
```

Comment: The second code fragment creates a copy of `i` in each loop, so when the timeout actually triggers you see the preserved state of `i`. The first example always references the same `i`, hence when the timeout finally triggers, they all show the final value of `i`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're passing `setTimeout()` the same lambda five times, each time with a reference to the same loop variable, `i`. For each call, the lambda is evaluated after the loop exits, when `i` is equal to `6` (`i++`, check if `i <= 5`, if not, break out of the loop).

The lambda has a reference to the variable itself, not to its value at the time the lambda was created. That's very useful in most cases. Just not this one.

The `var j;` version has *two* lambdas. The one with `var j = i;` is executed immediately, with the current value of `i`. That creates a new variable `j`, local to that lambda. `j` is initialized with the value of `i` that was current at the time the outer lambda was executed. So in that case, you're giving `setTimeout()` what you may as well consider five different lambdas, with five different variables, all named `j`, but with five different values.

The inner lambda is executed later, but it uses `j`.

What differs is the code has created a unique location to store each *value* of `i`.

Final point: In some other languages, this would work:

```
for (var i=1; i<=5; i++) {
    var j = i;
    setTimeout( function timer(){
        console.log( j );
    }, j*1000 );

}
```

In JavaScript, it does not. The scope of `j` differs. In JavaScript, there will only be one `j` in that case. That's why the immediately executed function is used: To ensure that there will be more than one `j`.